# How to link a single file from the drupalcode.org git repository in the newest version?

Tags: git, drupal, hyperlink, makefile

You can link to a the drush make file of commerce_kickstart like this:

http://drupalcode.org/project/commerce_kickstart.git/blob_plain/2abeb052d6cb4afb2450bc4b01bbbc011dbeeb0d:/commerce_kickstart.make

This link gives you for example the version of Tue Mar 26 09:15:43 2013 GMT from 
http://drupalcode.org/project/commerce_kickstart.git

Is there a way to generate a link that always goes to the latest version of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HEAD instead of a specific commit.

http://drupalcode.org/project/commerce_kickstart.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/commerce_kickstart.make